# How much Indian currency can I carry to Thailand from India?

Tags: india, money, thailand

I will be moving back to Thailand, as I got job there. How much Indian currency can I carry when I travel to Thailand alone?

I have tried to transfer online, which was not possible for me.

Comment: While this question, in a general sense, could be considered topical to [travel.se] ... in the specifics, it is off-topic and should be migrated to [expatriates.se]

Answer (score 2):

It is not legal to carry Indian currency notes out of India. Once you have a bank account in Thailand you can do a wire transfer from your Indian bank account.

You can also buy Thai currency from India and take it with you but the value should not exceed USD10000.

Another way to do this would be to just take your visa or mastercard debit card with you and draw the money in Thailand using your Indian card but this will carry some extra fees and the exchange rate you get wont be very good either.

Comment: Actually importing Thai Baht is limited to 50,000 Baht for a single traveler, which is about US$1600.  Importing foreign currency is "unlimited" but any amount more than US$20,000 must be declared to customs upon arrival.

Answer (score 1):

Refer to this official information from Indian customs: 
http://www.cbec.gov.in/trvler-guide_ason22may2013.pdf

> Export of Indian Currency is strictly prohibited. However Indian
>   residents when they go abroad are allowed to take with them Indian
>   currency not exceeding Rs. 7,500.

Comment: 7,500 INR is less than $120 USD.  What a huge pain in the ass.

Comment: what are you going to do with the INR in thailand? Just take USD/EUR with you and should be more than sufficient!

Comment: You can ask the OP what he planned to do specifically, but it is the essence of tyranny to ask "Why would a law-abiding person _want_ to do this thing I am making unlawful?"  The point is, the OP has some reason that he himself finds sufficient and he should not have to justify himself to anyone not involved.